# Ruby expression

Tags: ruby, regex

```
(?:)
```

It is a valid ruby regular expression, could anyone tell me what it means?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not capture the part of the matching string in a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex) (i.e \1).

Comment: @gpojd, How should I understand the '?' and ':' here?

Comment: For example, (\d+) will capture consecutive digits in a backreference like \1.  If you want to group part of the regex, but do not want to capture them, you would use (?:\d+).  Needlessly capturing the data can decrease performance.

Answer (score 9):

Like others have said, it's used as the non-capturing syntax for a regex, but, it's also valid ruby syntax outside of a regex.

In ruby `?:` is the integer value for the colon character:

```
% irb
irb> ?:
=> 58
irb ":"[0]
=> 58
```

Adding parenthesis doesn't change the value: `(?:) == ?:`

When you add spaces (`? :`), it's the ternary operator, which is essentially shorthand for if/then/else in ruby, so the statement `( bool ? truish : falsy )` is equivalent to

```
if bool then 
  truish 
else 
  falsy 
end
```

Comment: ?: evaluates to '?' in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

This is an empty, [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). It has no meaning in this case and can be dropped.